# Underhanded Solidity: Exploiting multiple inheritance

Tags: solidity, security, inheritance

In an article by Steve Marx [(on Medium.com)](https://medium.com/consensys-diligence/a-case-against-inheritance-in-smart-contracts-d7f2c738f78e), the author argues against using inheritance in solidity not only because of harder readability of a Smart Contract, but also because it can be exploited in an ***underhanded fashion***.

To support his claim, he poses the following vulnerable `Bank` contract:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.10;

contract Admin {
    address admin = msg.sender;

    function isAdmin() internal view returns (bool) {
        return msg.sender == admin;
    }
}

// Support adding extra admins.
contract MultiAdmin is Admin {
    mapping(address => bool) extraAdmins;

    function addAdmin(address who) external {
        require(isAdmin());
        extraAdmins[who] = true;
    }
    function isAdmin() internal view returns (bool) {
        return extraAdmins[msg.sender] || super.isAdmin();
    }
}

// Support permanently disabling admin functionality.
contract TempAdmin is Admin {
    bool administratable = true;
    function disableAdmin() external {
        require(isAdmin());
        administratable = false;
    }
    function isAdmin() internal view returns (bool) {
        return administratable && super.isAdmin();
    }
}

// To start with, only admins can deposit, and they can selfdestruct
// the contract if needed to recover from bugs. Once the testing
// phase is over, an admin will call disableAdmin(), and then the
// bank is open for business.
contract Bank is TempAdmin, MultiAdmin {
    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;

    function deposit() external payable {
        if (administratable) {
            require(isAdmin(), "Admins only during testing.");
        }
        balanceOf[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    }

    function withdraw() external {
        uint256 amount = balanceOf[msg.sender];
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = 0;
        msg.sender.transfer(amount);
    }
    function kill() external {
        require(isAdmin());
        selfdestruct(msg.sender);
    }
}
```

He argues:
The expected behaviour is for the deployers to call **`disableAdmin()`** once the contract is off its testing period, and thus we expect the **`kill()`** function to be inaccessible.

BUT

Due to how `contract Bank` inherits `is TempAdmin, MultiAdmin`, `kill()` can still be ran and will succeed, therefore admins can suicide the contract and run off with everyone's ether.

The author says that this is due to Solidity following [C3 Linearization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization): Because of how inheritance is resolved, the `require(isAdmin());` in `kill()` results in the equivalent check of `extraAdmin[msg.sender] || (administratable && msg.sender == admin)`, which of course is vulnerable and allows the `require(isAdmin())` to return true, and `kill()` continues execution.

**I fail to see how he reaches this conlusion**, any help understanding if the article author's claim is valid?

How is inheritance resolved when you've got multiple parents with the same function name?

Comment: Partially related question [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/82866). This type of inheritance is not even supported in Solidity as far as I know. And in either case, the arguments mentioned in this claim cannot be used for other (non-diamond) types of inheritance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'exploit' no longer applies to solc v0.6, since then the compiler generates an error when there's an ambiguous call.

---

As the author says solc v0.5 uses C3 linearization to determine the order in which functions will be called.

In the cited example the C3 linearization order is [`Bank`, `MultiAdmin`, `TempAdmin`, `Admin`].

When `funct()` is called the first implementation in the order will be executed. It can call the next in the sequence with `super.funct()`.

Continuing with the example `isAdmin` resolves to `MultiAdmin.isAdmin()`

```
extraAdmins[msg.sender] || super.isAdmin()
```

Which invokes the next `TempAdmin.isAdmin()`

```
administratable && super.isAdmin();
```

Which calls the next and final `Admin.isAdmin()`

```
msg.sender == admin
```

Putting all of this together we get

```
(extraAdmins[msg.sender] || (administratable && (msg.sender == admin)))
                                               \_______ Admin ______/
                           \___________ TempAdmin ___________________/
\____________________ MultiAdmin _____________________________________/
```

---

#### How can we fix this?

In the cited example an easy and bad fix is to swap `MultiAdmin` and `TempAdmin` in the defintion of `Bank`

```
contract Bank is MultiAdmin, TempAdmin {
```

It works for `isAdmin` but this change will also affect other functions that we haven't considered. How can we prevent someone else to swap them at a later time? Or to add another inheritance that will change the C3 order? Unfortunately there's no guarantee.

I'd prefer to not depend on C3 linearization if there's some ambiguity.

In the example why do three contracts change `isAdmin` behavior? Isn't it better to concentrate all such properties in one contract instead?

Comment: `no longer applies to solc v0.6` - as stated in [the official documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.0/contracts.html#multiple-inheritance-and-linearization).

Comment: Maybe I need to brush up on my Compiler Theory courses, but I fail to see how `MultiAdmin`'s `super.isAdmin()` resolves to `TempAdmin.isAdmin()` and it doesn't just directly go to `Admin.isAdmin()` then gets `&&`ed with `TempAdmin.isAdmin()`. In any case, thank you for mentioning this "exploit" is invalidated by Solidity 0.6.0+

Comment: @DimitrisSfounis Solidity does the linearization from right to left, the reverse of python, https://github.com/federicobond/c3-linearization#important-notes.